# Filling entity links in custom @RepositoryRestController methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am using Spring-data-rest to provide read APIs over some JPA entities.
For writes I need to issue Command objects rather than directly write to the DB, so I added a custom controller using `@RepositoryRestController` and various command handling methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MyEntity post(@RequestBody MyEntity entity) {
  String createdId = commands.sendAndWait(new MyCreateCommand(entity));
  return repo.findOne(createdId);
}
```

I would like the output to be enriched just like any other response by the spring-data-rest controller, in particular I want it to add HATEOAS links to itself and its relations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has recently been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782016/3790806) (see point 3.) by [Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke) himself (the question used quite different keywords though, so I won't flag this as duplicate).

The example for a single entity would become:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(@RequestBody MyEntity entity,
    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler)) {
  String createdId = commands.sendAndWait(new MyCreateCommand(entity));
  return resourceAssembler.toResource(repo.findOne(createdId));
}
```

The example for a non-paginated listing:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Resources<PersistentEntityResource> post(
    @RequestBody MyEntity entity,
    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler)) {
  List<MyEntity> myEntities = ...
  List<> resources = myEntities
      .stream()
      .map(resourceAssembler::toResource)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  return new Resources<PersistentEntityResource>(resources);
}
```

Finally, for a paged response one should use an injected PagedResourcesAssembler, passing in the method-injected ResourceAssembler and the Page, rather than instantiating Resources. More details about how to use `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` and `PagedResourcesAssembler` can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29924387/3790806). Note that at the moment this requires to use raw types and unchecked casts.

There is room for automation maybe, better solutions are welcome.

P.S.: I also created a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-633) to add this to Spring Data's documentation.

Comment: would this be a more detailed example of Gierke's option 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29924387/1938607 ?

Comment: There are some important bits still missing: 1) how do you get from a "`MyEntity`" to a `PersistentEntityResource`. 2) The example targeted at a paginated collection, for a single entity the process is different. I will try by myself to solve these,.

Comment: Solved easily for a single resource and updated the answer. It is still counter-intuitive to have a resourceAssembler injected on the method and repetitive to call toResource for every handler. It would be nice if building a resource could happen automatically by returning just the entity. I'll wait a little before flagging as accepted, to see if improvements come up.

Comment: Since this is the way the lead developer of Spring Data described, I doubt it.