# Spring HATEOAS custom controller - enable converting URI to entity

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

This is an example of what I would like to achieve:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addCompletedTask")
    public void addCompletedTask(User user, Task task) {
        user.getCompletedTasks().add(task);
        task.incrementCompletedBy();
        userRepository.save(user);
        taskRepository.save(task);
    }
}
```

Then I would make a request like this:

```html
POST http://localhost:8080/api/users/addCompletedTask
{
 "user": "http://localhost:8080/api/db/users/59fa19bfd58dcf25e82082b2",
 "task": "http://localhost:8080/api/db/tasks/59fa19bfd58dcf22d2322312"
}
```

I tried to wrap arguments to the method with `Resource<User>`, add `@RequestBody`, nothing works, everything is `null`.

I don't know if it's possible, but I've seen examples of people writing code like this, so maybe I'm missing something ([here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41512744/4896651)). Or maybe is there some way to do that through the repository in one call? I can add a task in one call, and increment counter in another, but that requires two calls from the client. Also I'm pretty sure I will encounter another situation similiar to this, so if there is a solution that would be great.

Comment: You need to ask about your real problem which can maybe be addressed by an event handler? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events 
  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is just an example, what I want is to simply give resource URI's in the request JSON and then have them in the controller as java objects. I would even be happy with knowing if that is possible without doing things manually, extending Spring classes etc, because maybe it's not possible.