# Spring Boot Controller: return resource in the same style like PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am a newbie with Spring Boot, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I am currently using the `PagingAndSortingRepository` to serve the resources of my REST API. But for some security reasons, I need to customize the results of the `GET` requests. Therefor I am implementing a controller for the Methods.

This is the Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dimensionAttributeValues")
public class DimensionAttributeValueController {

    @Autowired
    DimensionAttribueValueService dimensionAttribueValueService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PageImpl<DimensionAttributeValue> getDimensionAttributeValues(Pageable pageable) {
        Authentication user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        List<DimensionAttributeValue> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (user.getAuthorities().contains("ADMIN")) {
            result = dimensionAttribueValueService.getAllDimensionAttributeValue();
        } else {
            result = dimensionAttribueValueService.getUserDimensionAttributeValue(user.getName());
        }

        return new PageImpl<DimensionAttributeValue>(result, pageable, result.size());
    } 
}
```

The Problem is, the controller does not return the resources in the same style as the Repository.

The result is looking similar to this:

```
{
   "content":[ {..}],
   "size":20,
   "totalElements":27,
   "totalPages":2   "number":0
}
```

What I like to have:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "dimensionAttributeValue" : [ {..}, ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/dimensionAttributes"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 37,
    "totalPages" : 2,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

---

**This question seems to be duplicated, thanks to @Adi.**

[Can I make a custom controller mirror the formatting of Spring-Data-Rest / Spring-Hateoas generated classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538156/can-i-make-a-custom-controller-mirror-the-formatting-of-spring-data-rest-sprin)

---

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538156/can-i-make-a-custom-controller-mirror-the-formatting-of-spring-data-rest-sprin