# @RepositoryRestController custom controller with RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to implement custom controller to handle method defined in custom repository to be able to expose resources using this method via REST (according to [Implementing custom methods of Spring Data repository and exposing them through REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201306/implementing-custom-methods-of-spring-data-repository-and-exposing-them-through?lq=1)).

Here is the configuration and other relevant code:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ApplicationConfig.class};
     }

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class};
     }

     @Override
     protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/api/*"};
     }

}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // data source settings
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        // em factory settings
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        // tx mng settings
    }
}
```

ExperimentRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ExperimentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Experiment, Long>,
    ExperimentRepositoryCustom {

    @RestResource(rel = "byName", path = "byName")
    Page<Experiment> findByNameContaining(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

ExperimentRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface ExperimentRepositoryCustom {

    Page<Experiment> findUsingCustomFilter(...);

}
```

ExperimentRepositoryImpl:

```
public class ExperimentRepositoryImpl implements ExperimentRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    public Page<Experiment> findUsingCustomFilter(...) {
        // search for experiment based on given filter
    }

}
```

ExperimentController:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class ExperimentController {

    @Autowired
    private ExperimentRepository experimentRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/experiments/search/findByFilter", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Experiment> searchUsingFilter(@RequestParam Long id) {
        // for test purpose call method from CrudRepository (will be replaced by findUsingCustomFilter(...)) 
        return new ResponseEntity(experimentRepository.findOne(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Project structure:

```
basepackage.model.Experiment
basepackage.repository.ExperimentController
basepackage.repository.ExperimentRepository
basepackage.repository.ExperimentRepositoryImpl
basepackage.repository.ExperimentRepositoryCustom
basepackage.ApplicationInitializer
basepackage.ApplicationConfig
```

All resources exposed by links automatically generated based on used Repositories are accessible with no problem but calling GET method on http://localhost:8080/app/api/experiments/search/findByFilter?id=1 ends with 404 (resources exposed by links automatically generated based on used Repositories work fine). I assume that ExperimentController is not registered in Spring container or I am missing some additional settings regarding controller method. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need configuration to load your Controllers. One way to do this is to add a configuration class to load you Controllers and add it to your ApplicationInitializer.

```
//PLACE THIS IN A PACKAGE WHERE YOUR CONTROLLERS ARE
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

@ComponentScan
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class WebConfig {
}
```

Change you `ApplicationInitializer` to

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.spring.data.rest.test.web.WebConfig;

public class ApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { ApplicationConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/api/*" };
    }

}
```