# How to force Spring HATEOAS resources to render an empty embedded array?

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I have the following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "session/{id}/exercises")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Exercise>> exercises(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

  Optional<Session> opt = sessionRepository.findWithExercises(id);
  Set<Exercise> exercises = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

  if (opt.isPresent()) {
    exercises.addAll(opt.get().getExercises());
  }

  Link link = entityLinks.linkFor(Session.class)
                         .slash(id)
                         .slash(Constants.Rels.EXERCISES)
                         .withSelfRel();

  return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources<>(exercises, link));
}
```

So basically I am trying to get the expose a `Set<>` of `Exercise` entities for a particular `Session`. When the exercises entity is empty however I get a JSON representation like this:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/sessions/2/exercises"
        }
    }
}
```

So basically there is no embedded entity, while something like the following would be preferrable:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/sessions/2/exercises"
        }
    }, 
    "_embedded": {
        "exercises": [] 
    }    
}
```

any idea how to enforce this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that without additional effort there's no way to find out that the empty collection is a collection for `Exercise`. Spring HATEOAS has a helper class to work around this though:

```
EmbeddedWrappers wrappers = new EmbeddedWrappers(false);
EmbeddedWrapper wrapper = wrappers.emptyCollectionOf(Exercise.class);
Resources<Object> resources = new Resources<>(Arrays.asList(wrapper));
```

An `EmbeddedWrapper` allows you to explicitly mark objects to be added to the `Resource` or `Resources` as embedded, potentially even manually defining the rel they should be exposed under. As you can see above the helper also allows you to add an empty collection of a given type to the `_embedded` clause.

Comment: This loses generic type information (and it's not the only case when assembling resources). I think it should be `EmbeddedWrapper<T> implements Resource<T>`, but Resource is no interface, and that's the root of the problems with generics in Spring HATEOAS, in my opinion.

Comment: For PagedResources result:
`List<EmbeddedWrapper> embedded = Collections.singletonList(wrapper);
PagedResources pagedResources = new PagedResources(embedded, metadata, links);`

Comment: @ccit-spence yes, [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36455266/343802)

Comment: I also stumbled upon this, I can make it work with using Object instead of my type for embeddedWrapper but I really don't like it. Why isn't this an option or the default? When using spring data rest an empty collection is the default as well.

Comment: @Oliver Gierke rather than this ugly workaround, why not extend the constructor instead? `new Resources<>(Exercise.class, exercises, ...);` is acceptable for me.

Comment: Please vote for https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/522 (just click the "add your reaction" button)

Comment: I am not happy with this workaround either. It requires some generics acrobatics to make the compiler happy. I find it odd that CrudRepository does include the empty _embedded json block while in the controller this workaround is needed to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3):

One can use the PagedResourceAssembler::toEmptyResource() method. For example, the following works:

```
Page<EWebProduct> products = elasticSearchTemplate.queryForPage(query, EWebProduct.class);

if(!products.hasContent()){
            PagedResources pagedResources = pageAssembler.toEmptyResource(products, WebProductResource.class,baseLink);
            return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<WebProductResource>>(pagedResources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'd bet it works with other ResourceAssemblers as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Page< T >, you can convert it like this:

```
 public static <T> PagedModel<EntityModel<T>> toModel(PagedResourcesAssembler<T> assembler,
                                                Page<T> page) {
        if (!page.isEmpty()) {
            return assembler.toModel(page);
        } else {
            // toEmptyModel renders the _embedded field (with an empty array inside)
            return (PagedModel<EntityModel<T>>) assembler.toEmptyModel(page, TenantSubscriptionResponseDto.class);
        }
    }
```

(You can obtain the *PagedResourcesAssembler assembler* by simply adding it as a parameter to the Controller method, and Spring will inject it).

Answer (score -1):

Spring by default uses Jackson parser to serialize/deserialize json. As per http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesSerialization Jackson has a feature called **WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS** and its enabled by default. Maybe **WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS** is set to `false` in your config. please recheck your message converters configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not this, it's not JSON array, it's an entire hierarchy of `_embedded` in Spring HATEOAS.