# Custom implementation in @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a spring-boot project which uses `@RepositoryRestResource`.

There are 2 entities, `Product` & `Domain`, which has many-to-many relation.

I want to implement a custom REST call which is running a complex query.

To implement custom implementation I'm following [this blog](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-data/spring-data-add-custom-method-to-repository/).

**ProductRepository Interface:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long>, CustomProductRepository {

    List<Product> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

**CustomProductRepository.java - Interface for custom REST call**

```
public interface CustomProductRepository {
    public List<Product> findByDomainName(String domainName);
}
```

**ProductRepositoryImpl.java - It's implementation. (I'm following the naming convention as mentioned in the blog)**

```
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements CustomProductRepository {

    @Override
    public List<Product> findByDomainName(long id, String domainName) {
        List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // Query logic goes here
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Updating ProductRepository.java to extend CustomProductRepository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long>, CustomProductRepository {

    List<Product> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

The application starts without error. I expect when I call `http://localhost:8080/product/search`, it should list my custom method: `findByDomainName`. But it doesn't.

All I get is:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "findByName" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/product/search/findByName{?name}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/product/search/"
    }
  }
}
```

Even when I call make a REST call to http://localhost:8080/product/search/findByDomainName, I get *404*.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have IntelliJ IDE check spring components in the bottom tab and see if your path is listed there...

Comment: @silentsudo, I'm using intellij, but not sure where I can see spring components. Can you point me to guide, which can help me?

Comment: you need to write the controller that listens to the endpoint you are hitting.

Comment: @joemokenela, will that not defeat the purpose of using `RepositoryRestResource`, that we don't have to write the controllers?

Comment: I didn't notice you are using the RepositoryRestResource annotation, On that note, you need to annotate your  CustomProductRepository  as well because your method findByDomainName is not exposed.

Comment: @joemokenela, but since we are extending `CustomProductRepository` in `ProductRepository`, doesn't that will make it as a Rest resource?

Comment: why do you expect `search` in path?

Comment: As per documentation, all exposed APIs will be mentioned in path. Regardless, question is how should i implement custom rest API within this code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201306/implementing-custom-methods-of-spring-data-repository-and-exposing-them-through

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible by design. The custom method would work though, if annotated with `@Query`.
See [implementing-custom-methods-of-spring-data-repository-and-exposing-them...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201306/implementing-custom-methods-of-spring-data-repository-and-exposing-them-through)