# Spring Boot MongoDB REST - Custom Repository Methods

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-rest and spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb as per the tutorial given [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/). I'm attempting to create a custom method for a MongoRepository, but having no success.

I've followed the steps given for [adding custom behavior to single repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour), but I'm getting a 404 error when I attempt to access the custom method.  Hitting the parent endpoint also shows no sign of the method, but I didn't expect it to do that.

Help me, please! What am I doing wrong!?

My code is as follows:

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ItemRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface ItemRepositoryCustom {
    void customMethod();
}
```

**ItemRepositoryImpl.java**

```
public class ItemRepositoryImpl {
    @Override
    public void customMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**ItemRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="items", path="items")
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String>, ItemRepositoryCustom {
    List<Item> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: Custom Repository are not allowed in Spring Data Rest as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116539/custom-jpa-repository-method-published-by-spring-data-rest.

Comment: Already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25217113/5873923 - can someone mark this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom implementation class name  from `ItemRepositoryImpl`  to `ItemRepositoryCustomImpl`.

I followed [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) here.

Cheers!