# Spring Data, Repository Rest Resource Call Inherited Methods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT employee FROM Employee employee")
    List<Employee> getAll();

    Page<Employee> findAll(Example<Employee> employeeExample, Pageable pageable);

}
```

If I call :

`.../api/employees/search/getAll` it gives me the result of `getAll` method

However JpaRepository has same function but I am unable to call it:

`.../api/employees/search/findAll`

Fortunately, I was able to write a `@Query` method that have same functionality.

But now I need to call [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.domain.Example-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-) method from `QueryByExampleExecutor`(JpaRepository extends this interface)

```
<S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> var1, Pageable var2);
```

I wrote some function to EmployeeRepository, in order to call it as rest endpoint.

```
Page<Employee> findAll(Example<Employee> employeeExample, Pageable pageable);
```

But I get the bellow error:

> findAll(Example, Pageable)' in
>   'com.foo.repository.EmployeeRepository' clashes with
>   'findAll(Example, Pageable)' in
>   'org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor';
>   both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I can not write a `@Query` method that has same functionality with that method.

**How can I call inherited repository methods as a Rest Enpoint in Spring-Data ?**

Comment: could be a duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201306/implementing-custom-methods-of-spring-data-repository-and-exposing-them-through 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116539/custom-jpa-repository-method-published-by-spring-data-rest

Comment: No, I just asked how can I call inherited methods as rest endpoint from Spring Jpa, there is no custom method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Correct signature is,

```
@Override
<S extends Employee> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable)
```

Comment: I tried your method, then I called "...api/employees/search". But I couldn't see the findAll method.